# Using javascript functions within php

Tags: php, javascript, class

I am trying to use the function changeClass to change the class of a table row:

```
<tr class="formatHTML5" onclick='changeClass(this,"class1","class2");'>


<script>
function changeClass(elem, className1,className2)
{
elem.className = (elem.className == className1)?className2:className1;
}
</script>
```

and this works fine, but when I try to echo it within php it doesn't seem to work:

```
echo "<tr class='formatHTML5' onclick='changeClass(this,'class1','class2');'>";
```

I cannot use the " marks inside the echo. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: to use " inside a String you need to escape them like: \" so: echo "<tr class='bls' onclick='changeClass( this, \"class2\", \"class2\" );' >";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to escape the quotes:

`echo "<tr class='formatHTML5' onclick='changeClass(this,\"class1\",\"class2\");'>";`

Comment: I escaped them and the syntax seems fine however the class isn't changing like it does outside php. For more context, my <script> is outside the php code.

Comment: I made it work by removing another function I had in the same line. It looked like this:

echo "<tr class='formatHTML5' onclick='selectRow(this)';'changeClass(this,\"formatHTML5\",\"new\");'>";

once I removed the selectRow(this) it worked. Does this not allow for multiple functions to work after the onclick? or would it be something the first function does?


function selectRow(row){var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;}

Comment: no, your syntax was just incorrect: `echo "<tr class='formatHTML5' onclick='selectRow(this); changeClass(this,\"formatHTML5\",\"new\");'>";` 
you ended the onclick='' after selectRow(), which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: are you not using a code editor/IDE? things like that should easily be spotted with the colored syntax.

Comment: I fixed it now by putting both functions into the one function. I was using dreamweaver as I am pretty noob at this sort of thing :P but it shows everything within the echo "" as red text so it's hard to tell when something is wrong.